# I don't understand the logic of the WordPress function 'is_super_admin'

Tags: php, wordpress, logical-operators, boolean-logic

I'm currently learning about the WordPress core and came across this function in my studies:

```
 /**
 * Determine if user is a site admin.
 *
 * @since 3.0.0
 *
 * @param int $user_id (Optional) The ID of a user. Defaults to the current user.
 * @return bool True if the user is a site admin.
 */
function is_super_admin( $user_id = false ) {
  if ( ! $user_id || $user_id == get_current_user_id() )
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
  else
    $user = get_userdata( $user_id );

  if ( ! $user || ! $user->exists() )
    return false;

  if ( is_multisite() ) {
    $super_admins = get_super_admins();
    if ( is_array( $super_admins ) && in_array( $user->user_login, $super_admins ) )
      return true;
  } else {
    if ( $user->has_cap('delete_users') )
      return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

I'm still a beginner programmer so this may be a dumb question, but the logic in that first if...else statement seems strange to me:

```
if ( ! $user_id || $user_id == get_current_user_id() )
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
else
    $user = get_userdata( $user_id );
```

Why do we need this logical comparison?

```
$user_id == get_current_user_id()
```

It seems to me if a $user_id is passed in, we should call get_userdata( $user_id ), and if NO $user_id is passed in, then we should call wp_get_current_user(), like so:

```
$user = $user_id ? get_userdata($user_id) : wp_get_current_user();
```

That whole comparison of $user_id == get_current_user_id() just adds extra work, right? What are some possible justifications for writing the function that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

! $user_id || $user_id == get_current_user_id()
 is statement is true so if the function is called with user_id to false OR if the passed user_id is in fact the current user, it is more efficient to simply load the current user. no database queries.

otherwise, if a user_id is specified, a query must be fired to get it's data.

the logic is OK :)